# How to create a Weekly recurrent event using OData query on SharePointOnline?

Tags: angular, typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm developing an intranet where we use sharpeoint online. I'm using OData to query sharepoint REST requests.

The client asked for a way of creating both recurrent and single events. While I'm able to create a single event I'm having some trouble creating a recurrent one.

The **add** is executed properly and the event is added to the Calendar but with a singularity.

This is my recurrence string

```
<recurrence>
    <rule>
        < firstDayOfWeek > su < /firstDayOfWeek>
        < repeat >
            <weekly tu='TRUE' we='TRUE'  weekFrequency= '1'/>
        < /repeat>
        < windowEnd >2018-08-22T09:12:26Z< /windowEnd > 
    < /rule>
</recurrence >
```

and this is my query

```
    if (newItem["Recurrent"]) {
        return new Web(`${this.baseUrl}`)
            .lists
            .getByTitle(this.baseList)
            .items
            .add({
                "Languages_Active": true,
                "Title": newItem["Title"],
                "Languages_PT": true,

                ["Title_" + language]: newItem["Title"],
                ["Description_" + language]: newItem["Description"],
                'Preferences': newItem["Preferences"],
                'fRecurrence': newItem["Recurrent"],
                'FromLocation': newItem["FromLocation"],
                'ToLocation': newItem["ToLocation"],
                'StopPoint': newItem["StopPoint"],
                'Seats': newItem["Seats"],
                'PrivateCar': newItem["PrivateCar"],

                'EventDate': newItem["StartDate"],
                'EndDate': newItem["EndDate"],

                //recurrent event fields
                'EventType': 1,
                'RecurrenceData': recurrenceString,
                'fAllDayEvent': false,
                'TimeZone': 0,
            })
            .then(createResult => {
                this.count(listName, country);
                this.home(refresh, listName, language, country);
            });
```

And this creates the item correctly appart from this field

[image: Recurrent Error]

This then makes the loader not being able to load the calendar events.

I've tried to create a event with a Custom recurrence but sharepoint doesn't allow this by default. I'm using **spEventsHelpers** to handle the recurrent events.

Am I able to stop creating a Custom Recurrence and make a Weekly one? I don't want to create complex recurrent events for now.

Also is this the expected result? Why can't I see the Pattern? I've been looking at this for hours and haven't figured out what the problem is...

I've searched for similar problems but found none...if you are aware of something of this sort please point it out.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when SharePoint cannot interpret the XML in the RecurrenceData field. Even though you have the correct syntax, there are a lot of extra spaces which consequently make the XML invalid. Here are a couple examples:

```
< firstDayOfWeek > su < /firstDayOfWeek>   //Incorrect         
<firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek>        //Correct

<weekly tu='TRUE' we='TRUE'  weekFrequency= '1'/> //Incorrect
<weekly tu='TRUE' we='TRUE' weekFrequency='1'/>   //Correct
```

I would recommend looking into the code that generates the XML for this field to eliminate the extra spaces. The final result needs to look like this:

```
<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><weekly tu='TRUE' we='TRUE' weekFrequency='1'/></repeat><windowEnd>2018-08-22T09:12:26Z</windowEnd></rule></recurrence>
```

Comment: Gonna test this and will provide feedback asap! Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yup! That solved the problem the event item creating problem.
Now it only gets stuck on the parser event, but that I think I can debug and get to the problem.

Thanks for the help mate